# return data from axios without it being a promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I made a fake api call to my json file with axios. I get a promise back from the function where i can get my data from. but i don't want that. I want to receive the data from the function.

my code now: products.js

```js
export default {
    getAllProducts(axios) {
        return axios.get('fakedb.json').then(response => {
            return response.data;
        });
    }
}
```

the view file: a product.vue file

```js
import productController from '~/data/controllers/product';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: productController.getAllProducts(this.$axios).then(res => this.products = res)
    }
  },
}
```

but this is not what i want to achieve.
what i want to achieve is this code in my product.vue file:

```
import productController from '~/data/controllers/product';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: productController.getAllProducts(this.$axios)
    }
  },
}
```

i want to receive the data without having to handle the promise in the view file. any solution how to return my data in the products.js file?

if i do a normal return from the products.js file like this it works fine:

```
export default {
    getAllProducts(axios) {
        return [
          {
              "name": "Product1",
               "price": 9.75
          },
          {
              "name": "Product2",
              "price": 10.75
          }
        ]

    }
}
```

But i want it to go with axios

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you have a .vue-file, I assume that this is a single-page vue component, right? And therefore you use vue-cli or webpack. I therefore assume that you can use async/await syntax.

Retrieving data from axios is asynchronous, because you basically cannot know how long it takes for it to retrieve the data over the network. And this kind of situation is what async/await is for.

So make the functions async:

products.js

```
export default {
    async getAllProducts(axios) {
        const response = await axios.get('fakedb.json');
        return response.data;
    }
}
```

product.vue:

```
import productController from '~/data/controllers/product';
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      products: [],
    };
  },
  async mounted: {
    this.products = await productController.getAllProducts(this.$axios);
  }
}
```

I do not think you can make the data function asynchronous, so return an empty data object (I have assumed that it is an array), and then use the `mounted` hook to retrieve data.

Comment: thanks. putting mu controller function in mounted helps

Comment: I want to use a model/controller system to make my vue project clear and this helps with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  A function returns immediately and there is nothing meaningful for it to return if you don't want a promise, since loading won't have begun yet.  This is the problem that promises solve to begin with.  It's a bad pattern to make an async call into your data to begin with, though.  Use this pattern instead:

```
data() {
  return {
    products: null
  }
},
methods: {
  getAllProducts() {
    return axios.get('fakedb.json').then(response => {
      this.products = response.data;
    });
  }
},
created() {
  this.getAllProducts();
}
```

The async call is abstracted out into the `created` hook, and when it's resolved it will set the data accordingly.

[Here's a little demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/oh65wsvc/)

Comment: thanks for helping, but because i want to use a controller/model system to make my project more managable i don't want to use the methods function for all my controller methods. the answer above is wat i want to achieve.

Comment: All that `methods` is doing here is putting the actual logic of the async call into its own place.  It makes it more valid syntax for the MVVM paradigm, not less.  Additionally, in a situation where you needed to reload the data, you could easily call the function again, which you cannot do from the answer you accepted.  Plus, there is no reason to use `mounted` instead of `created`.

Comment: yes it's nice you helped and it is correct. but it didnt asnwer the question i asked and i don't want it this way in my situation. You will get the upvote. but in this situation the other solution helped the most.

Comment: @Eric I don't care about the points, I commented in order to help you understand that my answer does the same thing as the one you accepted, just with slightly different syntax. It's ok if that's unclear to you, but I assure you it does. That was the purpose of the demo...